# Xml Reader.ReadString not returning string

Tags: xml, xmlreader

I am using xml reader to read my xml file and store a part of the xml file contents in a variable.I am able to see the contents in console only but not able to store the result in a variable to use it later.How to store the contents of a xml file in a variable?Below is my code

```
  var data = new Issue();

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("SeleniumTest.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    //return only when you have START tag

                    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                    {
                        case "Message":
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());

                            data.fields.description = reader.Value.ToString();

                            break;

                    }
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

`XmlReader` reads whatever it has under its internal position pointer. If you read the string by using `ReadString()` method it will move the pointer to the next element and the next time you try to get something it will not be at the same position.
If it works for the `Console.WriteLine` then do this:

```
var content = reader.ReadString();
Console.WriteLine(content);
data.fields.description = content;
```